# Remove title shadow from shadowed button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to remove shadow from my button title.

How I make shadow and corner radius:

```
func makeShadowRounded() {
    layer.cornerRadius = 25
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    layer.shadowRadius = 3
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15
}
```

My button with white background:

```
let signInButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.customBlue.cgColor
    button.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    button.setTitle("Sign In", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.customBlue, for: .normal)
    button.makeShadowRounded()
    return button
}()
```

For removing/replacing (by different color) shadow i replaced `setTitle and setTitleColor` by:

```
    let shadow = NSShadow()
    shadow.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 2

    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Sign In", attributes: [
            NSAttributedStringKey.shadow : shadow,
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.customBlue
        ])

    button.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)
```

However, It isn't working properly. What will be the better solution for that issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. you're adding an attributed text with shadow but you're asking to remove it. why don't you remove it from the attributed string?

Comment: I have button with shadow, also have white background. Title of button also gets that shadow. I want to remove that shadow from button title.